# Restful API URL to get json data for different file type format

Tags: rest, api-design

I'm constructing restful API URLs to get products data. So I have,

```
POST /products
GET /products
GET /products/{:id}
DELETE /products/{:id}
```

One of requirement is to provide endpoints to get product data in JSON for exporting to different file format, CSV and PDF. It will be called by other service (export service).

Example of the response:

for PDF

```
{ 
  products_pdf: {
     title: 'Products',
     sub_title: 'as per May 20 2018',
     products: [
       {
          name: 'product A', 
       },
       {
          name: 'product B', 
       }
     ]
  }
}
```

for CSV, simpler response than PDF. Based on requirement, both can't be served in one response.

```
{
  products_csv: [
    {
      name: 'product A',
    },
    {
      name: 'product B'
    } 
  ]
}
```

What is the proper restful URL endpoint for it?

I'm thinking of like

```
GET /products/exports/{:file_format}
GET /products/exports/csv
GET /products/exports/pdf
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me, the format of the data is *optional* and as such should not dictate the resource endpoint. The most logical solution to me would be to have a default format and use a query string parameter to override e.g.

```
GET /products?format={pdf|csv}
```

Comment: How do you write that inside the code above the endpoint method definition? And what annotation do you need to add in the value object class fields to account for CSV?

Answer (score 2):

The old Google Finance API provided historical data in a variety of formats. These formats could be requested via different arguments to the query string parameter `output`.

For example:

`http://www.google.com/finance/historical?q=GOOGL&output=csv`

You would design the endpoint to handle the parameter and return a response in a format according to the output argument specified. If an invalid output type was provided, select a default of your choosing/which is most suitable for your particular data.

Answer (score 1):

IMO, Having the word **exports** in the URL doesn't look good. The endpoint can have the response type in the url extension.

Ex :

```
/products.json
/products.xml
/products.pdf
/products.csv
```

If you don't like this pattern, you can very well use the [Accept HTTP header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept).